# postgressql insert a date funciton

Tags: postgresql

I keep trying to reformat this date to get it to accept it.  I have tried everything.  Any help would be appreicated.  Thank you

```
INSERT INTO well.production_monthly(
    api10, prod_date,  oil, gas, water)
    VALUES (4246141341,02/01/2012, 102, 27, 0);
```

> Error ERROR:  column "prod_date" is of type date but expression is of
> type integer LINE 3:  VALUES (4246141341,02/01/2012, 102, 27, 0);
> ^ HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression. SQL state: 42804 Character: 95

Comment: Put quotes around your date and see what happens.

Comment: single quotes at that

Comment: See previous comments. As you have it written you are doing 2 divided by 1 divided by 2012 and since all the numbers are integers it is doing integer division which results in 0. So: `select 02/01/2012; 0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not have easy postgressql database just at the moment. But a google search seems to show it is the same as SqlServer, that is to say (the single quotes are part of it ''):

'YYYY-MM-DD'
**'2012-01-02'**

Including Time:
'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.[fractions of a second]'
**'2012-01-02 23:59:59.999'**

Between single quotes, the number descends in value From Year to Month, to Day, to Hour, to Minute, to Seconds, to Fractions of a Second.

Comment: postgres supports [a number of formats](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/datatype-datetime.html#AEN5595)